# How is $x' = Ax$ related to $x^{(n)} + p_{n-1}x^{(n-1)} + \cdots + p_0x = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $x' = Ax$ having $n$ solutions $r_1, r_2, \cdots, r_n$, how is this similar to the homogenous differential equation $x^{(n)} + p_{n-1}x^{(n-1)} + \cdots + p_0x = 0$? Are the elements $p_j$'s in some way a function of $a_{rc} = A[r][c]$ for $1 \leq r,s \leq n$?

Is it that the upon expanding the matrices, we get a system of equations which then gives us $x_i = x^{(i)}$ and $p_j$ a matrix consisting of the $a_{rc}$ elements? I do not see a different way, but I can not derive this either.

Comment: Assuming $A$ is constant, the result follows immediately from Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: Using substitution $x_1=y, x_2=y', \ldots, x_{n}=y^{(n-1)}$ one can transform the equation $y^{(n)}+p_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+\ldots+p_0y=0$ into the system $x'=Ax$, with specific matrix $A$.

Comment: @richrow If you mean $x = [x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n]^{\text{T}}$, can you tell me why they satisfy that substitution?

Comment: @user10354138 I don't understand, would you mind explaining it a bit more?

Comment: The corresponding system would be $x_k'=x_{k+1}$ for $k=\overline{1,n-1}$ and $x_{n}'=-p_0 x_1-\ldots-p_{n-1}x_{n}$. Is it clear now?

Comment: @richrow I don't see how exactly you get the relationship between the $x_j$'s (as you wrote $x'_k = x_{k+1}$).